# Move all files in s3 bucket from s3 account to another using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to move the contents of a bucket from **account-a** to a bucket in **account-b** which I already have the credentials for both of them.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
import boto3

SRC_AWS_KEY = 'src-key'
SRC_AWS_SECRET = 'src-secret'

DST_AWS_KEY = 'dst-key'
DST_AWS_SECRET = 'dst-secret'
srcSession = boto3.session.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=SRC_AWS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SRC_AWS_SECRET
)
dstSession = boto3.session.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=DST_AWS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=DST_AWS_SECRET
)
copySource = {
    'Bucket': 'src-bucket',
    'Key': 'test-bulk-src'
}
srcS3 = srcSession.resource('s3')
dstS3 = dstSession.resource('s3')
dstS3.meta.client.copy(CopySource=copySource, Bucket='dst-bucket', Key='test-bulk-dst', SourceClient=srcS3.meta.client)
print('success')
```

The problem is that when I specify a file's name in the field `Key` followed by `/file.csv` it works really fine, but when I set it to copy the whole folder, as showed in the code, it fails and throws this exception:

> **botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found**

What I need to do is to move the contents in one call, not by iterating through the contents of the src-folder, because this is time/money consuming, as I may have thousands of files to be moved.

Comment: `aws s3 sync s3://source_bucket/ s3://dest_bucket/`. No need for custom code.

Comment: Also, s3 technically does have folders or directories. It's a flat object store. The "prefix" is just part of the object name.

Comment: how can I run it in python (it's mandatory for me to use python)? and set the credentials for the source and destination?

Comment: awscli is written in python

Answer (score 0):

There is no API call in Amazon S3 to copy folders. (Folders do not actually exist — the Key of each object includes its full path.)

You will need to iterate through each object and copy it.

The AWS CLI (written in Python) provides some higher-level commands that will do this iteration for you:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://source-bucket/folder/ s3://destination-bucket/folder/
```

If the buckets are in different accounts, I would recommend:

- Use a set of credentials for the **destination account** (avoids problems with object ownership)
- Modify the bucket policy on the **source bucket** to permit access by the credentials from the destination account (avoids the need to use two sets of credentials)